# Unable to locate a label with label name using contains method of xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have following `HTML` code :

```
<li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in RentTenantPreference.options">
    <label class="ng-binding">
        <input class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="checkbox" checklist-value="option.id" ng-disabled="fieldLocks['RentPref']" ng-model="checked" checklist-model="formObj.occ_r" style=""/>
        Family
    </label>
</li>
```

I am trying  to locate the label using `//label[contains(text(),'Family')]` xpath but unable to do that.

Comment: <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in RentTenantPreference.options">
<label class="ng-binding">
<input class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="checkbox" checklist-value="option.id" ng-disabled="fieldLocks['RentPref']" ng-model="checked" checklist-model="formObj.occ_r" style=""/>
 Family
</label>
</li>

Comment: Please include all the components in your question rather than in the comments. Your are much more likely to get an answer that way. Also you can then use the code sample tags to format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
//label[contains(.,'Family')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's something messy with the html, don't know what yet, but you can try a different approach, select all label element and check if their texts contains 'Family' :

```
label_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//label')
for label_element in label_elements:
    if 'Family' in label_element.text:
        #dosomething with current element(label_element)
```

I hope this workaround can work for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try using anyone of the following xpaths, as the Text was inside the 'input' tag

//label[descendant::input[contains(text(),'Family')]] (stays in the label field itself)

or

//label/input[contains(text(),'Family')] (move to the input field inside the label)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are missing the correct xPath
Use below code-

```
.//*[contains(text(),'Family')]
```

Hope it will help you.